# How do you set X-Forward* for Traefik with Docker-Compose?

Tags: docker, https, docker-compose, traefik, fastapi

I'm using Traefik with a few FastAPI Docker containers (not using swarm). Everything is working perfectly except my Jinja2 templates are rendering `http` prefixes when I make references like `{{ url_for('assets', path='css/styles.css') }}` and `{{request.url}}`. From what I've read, this means that I need to force-set X-Forwards*.

I can't seem to find any documentation about using the docker-compose style settings that I've used thus far. My current docker-compose for the fastapi container that isn't forwarding

```
  fastapi:
    container_name: "fastapi"
    image: "fastapi:latest"
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      labels:
        - fastapi
    volumes:
        - .:/app
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      # Enable Traefik for this specific "backend" service
      - traefik.enable=true
      # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
      - traefik.http.services.fastapi.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTP
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-http.rule=Host(`${WEBSITE_URL?Variable not set}`)
      # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      # Make Traefik use this domain in HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-https.rule=Host(`${WEBSITE_URL?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-https.tls=true
      # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-https.tls.certresolver=le
      # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # Middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-http.middlewares=https-redirect

    networks:
      - traefik-public

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

I've tried adding all of the following without any success:

```
  - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=http

  - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https

  - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-https.rule=Host(`${WEBSITE_URL?Variable not set}`) && Headers(`X-Test`, `https`)

  - traefik.http.routers.fastapi-https.rule=Host(`${WEBSITE_URL?Variable not set}`) && Headers(`X-Forwarded-Proto`, `https`)
```

Would really appreciate it if anyone knows how to fix this.

Comment: What RUN command is inside your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

responding to all points here because other people might come accross the issue, but using only the last point should be enough in your case

---

If what you want is adding a custom header "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" in all calls to your fastapi endpoint, your second try :

```
- traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https
```

is the way to go; see the [headers middleware docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.3/middlewares/headers/)

(I would have put it in a distinct name than "https-redirect")

- Note : Also keep in mind that the X-forwarded are not always displayed by browers [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679620/traefik-docker-not-setting-x-forwarded-headers)

---

One can also use the [Forwarded headers rooting options](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.3/routing/entrypoints/#forwarded-headers) that allow to forward all headers and not just the X-Forwarded-Proto

---

This is if you want to patch your fastapi issue using traefik powers, however I would recommend to fix the root issue with the jinja2 templates using solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521784/fastapi-links-created-by-url-for-in-jinja2-template-use-http-instead-of-https)

I think it is simpler and safer to make the jinja2 templates use https from the beginning

Hopes this helps