# Using Python FastAPI. Web server running apache how to serve static folder over HTTPS

Tags: python, apache, fastapi

When using FastAPI all files in my static folder are served over HTTP and not HTTPS. To be more clear they're not being severed over my domain but the localhost of my webserver. I'm assuming this is something between how my webserver is setup and the mount function of FastAPI.

I'm hosting using Apache, with a domain, static IP, and https certificate. No issues with Flask or NodeJS on the same server.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates/")

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.get("/home/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def home(request: Request):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request})
```

ERROR:

```
Mixed Content:  
The page at 'https://www.<insert-domain>.com' was loaded over HTTPS,   
but requested an insecure element 'http://localhost:3000/static/logo.png'.  
This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS,  
For more information see
```

https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome blocks FastAPI file download using FileResponse due to using HTTP instead of HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301527/chrome-blocks-fastapi-file-download-using-fileresponse-due-to-using-http-instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Try to include the needed `ssl` configuration in your application,
that way `FastAPI` would know how to serve server over `HTTPS`.
Please try the following:

```py
app = FastAPI(
    ssl_keyfile="/path/to/your/private.key",
    ssl_certfile="/path/to/your/certificate.crt"
)
```

#### The Reason You Get This Error

You get the mentioned error about mixing both secure and insecure elements in your website. It seems like you access your domain it has the needed `SSL` certificates, but when you access the static files that are stored locally you are fetching things from `localhsot` without knowing they exist. `FastAPI` the way you've configured it does not know how to serve those files over `HTTPS`. Thus, you get the exact problem of accessing `https://www.example.com` and `http://localhost` at the same time which is no longer supported by chrome.

#### Resolving the Issue

In order to create a `FastAPI` app and configure it in a way it is served securely, you need to mention the `ssl` keys and certificates as part of the configuration on the application. That way, when you are accessing the site, you'll have `HTTPS`. Adding the needed `ssl_keyfile` and `ssl_certfile` as parameters to `FastAPI` constructor should do the trick. (Please see the above code snippet)

#### HTTPS Is More Complex than That

I highly recommend taking the time to dive deep into the subject and [read more about the subject](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/https/) at `FastAPI` documentation site. As mentioned there:

> It is easy to assume that HTTPS is something that is just "enabled" or not.
> But it is way more complex than that.

#### Some Things to Notice Before Hitting Production

You should consider multiple factors when you deploy your site.
According to your description of the error, it seems like something might not be configured correctly.
For some reason, the server access `localhost` in order to fetch the logo of the site/application. This might work when you are in the development area, but when you reach production environment is might break things. I would expect the server to fetch all static files from the server (using the domain) without trying to access some local stuff. Make sure the server is configured the right way.

#### Further Reading

If you are looking for some further examples about configuration for running the server manually, you can read more about that in the following blog posts:

- [How to host my api with an ssl certificate?](https://docs.masternetwork.dev/host-an-api-with-ssl/)
- [FastAPI over HTTPS for development on Windows](https://dev.to/rajshirolkar/fastapi-over-https-for-development-on-windows-2p7d)

If you are interested in checking the best practices regarding deployment settings, the `FastAPI` documentation site would be a good start - covering the basics and offering some ground rules:

- [FastAPI - Deployment - Intro](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/)
- [FastAPI - Deployment - Deployment Concepts](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/concepts/)